# Get only child elements of one taxonomy WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need small help here, I am trying to get only child elements of an taxonomy on my custom taxonomy. I succeed in retrieving items and the parent categories but I need child only, it works for some posts and I have no idea why and how.

Below is a code I tried:

```
$terms = get_terms('project_countries');
                        foreach($terms as $term) {
                        $posts = get_posts(array(
                            'post_type' => 'projects',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'project_countries',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'hierarchical' => 0, 
                            'include_parent' => false,
                            'terms' => $term->slug
                            )
                        ),
                            'numberposts' => -1
                        ));

                        foreach($posts as $post) {
                            echo $term->name;
                        $allname=$post->post_title.'</br>';
                        print_R($allname);
                            }
                        }
```